# Terminal never loading

Tags: macos, shell, terminal, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I have oh-my-zsh shell setup on my mac and today for some reason it never completely loads. It's been hanging like this for 10+ mins. I've tried closing my terminal app and reopening and no luck.

How can I debug this and/or simply open a new terminal with bash or something?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Seems it's related to the `npx` plugin https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/issues/7972

Answer (score 0):

Try running `zsh -xv` to get to help debug and get a printout as to what is going on. It may indicate where it freezes up. There are a number of articles on GitHub about oh-my-zsh running slow and freezing due to issues with scripts/.profile running.

https://bennycwong.github.io/post/speeding-up-oh-my-zsh/ --> an article on speeding it up